# Basic If statement

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

Can someone help me with my `if statement`? I am trying to make two checks when people visit my website. 1st one checks the connection type if its not a Broadband connection it sends the header redirecting to google. The 2nd one checks to see if the ip address is a known proxy if so it sends the header directing to google. My problem is no matter if its a proxy or not it always sends the header, and same for the connection type no matter which one it sends the header. What am I doing wrong?

```
HERE ARE THE OPTIONS FOR $TYPE.
$type = "Corperate";
$type = "Dial-Up";
$type = "Broadband";


//Block based on connection type
if ($type != "Broadband") {
    header('Location: http://www.google.com');
} else {
    //Do Nothing
}


HERE ARE THE OPTIONS FOR $PROXY.
$proxy = "Suspected Network Sharing Device";
$proxy = "Known Proxy";
//Block based on proxy
if (strlen($proxy) > 0) {
    header('Location: http://www.google.com');
} else {
     //Do nothing
}
```

Comment: Not enough information. Can you print out the values of `$type` and `$proxy` and post them here?

Comment: I'm assuming that you have mixed your comments in with the code.  As written this will not run.  It also appears that you set $type to "Broadband" right before testing if it equals "Broadband" and the same for testing $proxy.  Please separate your code and notes.

Comment: Is $proxy empty if it is not set?

Comment: How do you propose to detect a proxy and/or broadband host? Do you have some magical sniffler that can tell?

Answer (score 0):

Dont both your options of $proxy have length>0 ?

I think it should be

```
if($proxy != "known_proxy"){
  header('Location:http://www.google.com')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if (!empty($proxy)) {
    header('Location: http://www.google.com');
}
```

instead.

Also, I'm not even sure that is your problem since both proxy "options" are not empty strings, therefore have a `strlen() > 0`.

The only way that if statement will return `false` is if you were to do `$proxy = ""`